# How to get the attribute value from an ion-option

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have the following Select Menu. I want to access the attr.id within the TypeScript-Class. Is this possible? I didn't found a way. `friends` multidimensional array.

```
   <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Service</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectService" name="service" (ionChange)="serviceSelected($event)">
               <ion-option selected disabled value="">Service auswählen:</ion-option>
                <ion-option *ngFor="let friend of friends" [attr.id]="friend[3]">{{friend[1]}}: {{friend[2]}} </ion-option> 
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
serviceSelected(friend) 
{
  // How can I get the attribute "id" from the selected value here? 
}
```